# how to store each array in a line

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

i a pretty new in python,  i have an array like

```
[[ 5.2897942e+01  2.2989739e-02  1.9979945e+00  7.9999998e-02]
 [ 5.3750526e+01  1.9291429e-01  2.0269539e+00  0.0000000e+00]
 [ 5.3803116e+01  3.6183926e-01  2.0289137e+00  0.0000000e+00]
 ...
 [ 3.8401384e+00 -1.4381756e+00 -1.7735560e+00  3.4000000e-01]
 [ 3.8257158e+00 -1.4192016e+00 -1.7645701e+00  2.5000000e-01]
 [ 4.0923753e+00 -1.5071962e+00 -1.8955611e+00  0.0000000e+00]]
```

i need to save each array in as a line in a txt file like :

```
5.2897942e+01  2.2989739e-02  1.9979945e+00  7.9999998e-02
5.3750526e+01  1.9291429e-01  2.0269539e+00  0.0000000e+00
....
```

how can i do it please

Comment: Use a `for` loop, what's the problem?

Comment: may be [this](https://stackoverflobw.com/questions/9565426/saving-numpy-array-to-txt-file-row-wise) or it may be duplicate..

Comment: I don't think op is using numpy.. @user77540 could you please share what you have tried so far and where you are running into a issue?

Comment: i tried: numpy.savetxt("MyFile.txt", scan, newline=" ")  , now how can i keep every 4 element in a line in txt file

Answer (score 0):

This **might** be what you want.  If not, describe more precisely why it does not solve your problem.

```
array = [[5.2897942e+01, 2.2989739e-02, 1.9979945e+00, 7.9999998e-02],
         [5.3750526e+01, 1.9291429e-01, 2.0269539e+00, 0.0000000e+00],
         [3.8401384e+00, -1.4381756e+00, -1.7735560e+00, 3.4000000e-01],
         [3.8257158e+00, -1.4192016e+00, -1.7645701e+00, 2.5000000e-01]]

with open('/tmp/numbers.txt', 'w') as f:
    for row in array:
        f.write('  '.join('{0:.7e}'.format(n) for n in row) + '\n')
```

Just replace /tmp/numbers.txt with the file name of your choice.

Comment: I got  an error TypeError: 'numpy.int32' object is not iterable

Comment: We can't say why you are getting an error without knowing the context.  You probably changed something in this example.  What was it?  The example is just an example, not a direct solution.  As your question was very vague, I had to guess.  I posted this example rather than asking questions.  Maybe it helps, maybe it will lead you to explain why it does not.